# GRPC server error : Transport failed

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Written GRPC server in java and client in python.
From python client request is going successfully to server but getting below error after calling resposneObserver.onCompleted(). Below is stack trace. Although confirmed that stack trace is generated from some background thread. Not from the thread which is calling onCompleted().

Stack Trace :
INFO 15104 --- [grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-1] io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport       : Transport failed

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(10) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 30)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1405)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1392)

it's my first attempt with GRPC stuff. Any help please ?

Comment: Looks like a bug, but is hard to tell without a more complete stack trace. Please provide a more complete stack trace. Filing an issue at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java seems appropriate.

Comment: Issue resolved when using spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE version. Error comes with spring boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE version. Probably some netty jars version mismatch issue.